# I am getting " EntityRef: expecting ';' error while creating xml through php "

Tags: php, xml, entityreference

This is my XML,I am using php code for creating this xml. Please see screenshot for code:[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LoggedErrors>
  <LoggedError>
  <DateTime>2018-03-30T10:28:28+00:00</DateTime>
  <Errors/>
  <Request>
    <FlightGroup>
      <ArrivalTime>
        <Hour>12</Hour>
        <Millisecond>0</Millisecond>
        <Minutes>20</Minutes>
        <Seconds>0</Seconds>
        <Day>12</Day>
        <DayOfWeek>Thursday</DayOfWeek>
        <Month>4</Month>
        <Year>2018</Year>
      </ArrivalTime>
    </FlightGroup>
   </Request>
 </LoggedError>
</LoggedErrors>
```

Comment: Please don't post code as images, also if your getting an error it would help to have the full error and any indication of where the error is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public  function printResult($raw_data){
    // adding Content Type
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    // Converts PHP Array to XML with the root element being 'root-element-here'
    $xml = Excellence_Envision_Helper_Errorflile::createXML('LoggedError', $raw_data);

    return $xml->saveXML();

    }
```

Try to remove this code from your function and I think it will work fine then.

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the xml has special characters as values and ';' is not included it throws the error. For Example, if '<' is replaced with < and ';' after '&lt' is forgotten, browser (at least Chrome) displays the same error.